# knn streaming with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, k-means

I am trying to perform knn streaming with Spark. The model it is getting built but I am unable to predict the values on test data. There's no error which is displayed while doing the prediction. I am using the following code as reference.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-clustering.html#streaming-k-means

Can someone please help me out with it as am unable to troubleshoot it further.

The problem I feel is that my testData is not in the desired format. Is my assumption right? Following is the testdata format

[image]